# Django Error - NoReverseMatch at /listings/1. Reverse for 'addcomment' with arguments '('',)' not found. (Creating a comment section)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new to Django and I think I'm having issues setting up a dynamic url. I'm creating a way to add comments to a page, called a listing. The listing page loaded fine before I added anything about comments. When I try to go to that particular listing, I get the error:

"NoReverseMatch at /listings/1. Reverse for 'addcomment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['addcomment/(?P[0-9]+)$']"

Any help is appreciated because even after looking at the documentation I am having trouble understanding how dynamic urls work/how to create them.
I think my html page might also have problems, in terms of pulling in the correct info with the url etc.

views.py

```
def addcomment(request, id):
    obj = Comments()
    obj.comment = request.POST.get("comment")
    obj.user = request.user.username
    obj.listingid = id
    obj.save()

    # returning the updated content
    print("displaying comments")
    comments = Comments.objects.filter(listingid=id)
    product = Listings.objects.filter(id=id)
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
        "product": product,
        "comments": comments
    })

def listingpage(request, id):
    comments = Comments.objects.get(listingid=id)
    item = Listings.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
        "i": item,
        "id": id,
        "comments": comments,
        })
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("auctions/create", views.create, name="create"),
    path("listings/<int:id>", views.listingpage, name="listingpage"),
    path("addcomment/<int:id>", views.addcomment, name="addcomment"),
]
```

models.py

```
class Listings(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    starting_bid = models.IntegerField()
    link = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, blank=True, 
    null=True)


class Comments(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    listingid = models.IntegerField()
```

Part of the HTML file for the listing page that adds comments:

```
<h2 class="card-title h2">ADD COMMENT</h2>

            <form action="{% url 'addcomment' product.id %}" 
method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" 
rows="4" placeholder="Your Comment"></textarea>
                </div>
                <p align="justify"><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
            </form>
        </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please post *code fragments*, not *images*: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not pass a variable with the name `product` to the `listing.html` template, only `i`, `id`, and `comments`. You thus should pass this as product:

```
def listingpage(request, id):
    comments = Comments.objects.get(listingid=id)
    item = Listings.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'auctions/listing.html', {
        'i': item,
        'id': id,
        'product': item,  # ← pass product
        'comments': comments,
    })
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have seen that, it worked.